# Find pattern in some mysql row with php

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, design-patterns, matching

I have a table with 2 column in mysql: id(auto_increment) and value(int 0/1). I want to find how many presence match the pattern "101" in the table with PHP. Example:

```
id | value
----------
1  |   1
2  |   1   --
3  |   0    |  => (1)
4  |   1   --
5  |   0     | => (2)
6  |   1   -- 
7  |   0
8  |   0
9  |   1
10 |   1
.. |   ..
.. |   ..
5000 |  1  --
5001 |  0    |  => (n)
5002 |  1  --
5003 |  1
...  |  ...
```

Using Array is faster than search the pattern through mysql (import the value of mysql to an array) ?

Any body know how to find how many presence of "101" in the whole rows using PHP ?

Thanks
-jack-

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's how you can do it in SQL.

```
select count(*) match_count
from TheTable t1
join TheTable t2 on t1.id+1 = t2.id
join TheTable t3 on t1.id+2 = t3.id
where t1.value = 1 and t2.value = 0 and t3.value = 1
```

Comment: Just a question, as I'm starting to learn more advanced queries: Could you use `t1`.`id` after `select` in order to return the id(s) of the row(s) that start this sequence?

Comment: Yes, you could. I originally wrote it that way, then noticed that the question said you wanted to know how many matches, not the specific positions.

Comment: @user2758001 My answer only references one table. It self-joins twice, assigning aliases `t1`, `t2`, and `t3` to the instances of the table.

Comment: Replace `TheTable` in my query with the actual name of your table.

Comment: Hi Barmar, thanks for the solution. Is there any restriction, how much is the maximum table aliasing we can have ? I mean, is it possible to make about 15 aliasing, so i can do it for 15 digits like "100100010010111" and we make it as  ..... join TheTable t15 on t1.id+14 = t15.id where t1.value = 1 and ...... and t15.value = 1 ?

Comment: You could. It's probably not the most efficient way to do it, though, because it requires the SQL engine to do a huge cross-product of 15 temporary tables.

Comment: Hi Barmar, if the result i get is: **Resource id #5** , where can the problem be ?

Comment: if i use mysql_fetch_array() to catch the query given value, i just got **Array** as result

Comment: That's what PHP displays if you try to echo an array. If you want to see the contents of an array, use `var_dump` or `print_r`. Or access specific elements with `$array['key']`. I think you need to read tutorials on using mysql with PHP.

Comment: Hi Barmar, i works ... the problem is at mysql_query using php. Thank you very much .... :)